# jQuery: index all within document and mark nth child

Tags: jquery

I have complex list and daily changing amount of items like this

```
ul
   li.title
   li.item 
   li.item
   li.title 
   li.item
/ul
```

I need to add different backgrounds to each .title item. Targeting them in css with nth-child or nth-type (like ul li.title:nth-type(2)) fails (I guess because they have siblings).

So how can I index all .title and add bg classes to 1th,2th,3th?

Comment: So are you asking for a CSS solution or a jQuery solution? The question text talks only about CSS but there's only a jQuery tag.

Comment: nth css selector are elemental selectors and do not take into account classes.  Please can you show the css you have tried so that we have a better understanding of what you are trying to do as your explanation isn't very clear

Comment: Not at all clear what expected results are

Comment: I'm asking jQuery solution since I cant figure out how to make it work with css alone. Please see https://codepen.io/clientagency/pen/BJeLdw

Answer (score -2):

With class, you can't have the index with css.
But you can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), setting `even`/`odd`:

```
li.title:nth-child(even) { background-color: #FF0; }
li.title:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #0CF; }
```

or stablish one function like `An+B`:

```
li.title:nth-child(4n-2){ background-color: #00F; }
li.title:nth-child(3n+1){ background-color: #F00; }
```

Even with this, you won't have what you want, because it will get the `li.title` parent (`<ul>`) and search for every `<li>` inside of it which corresponds to the function passed to the pseudo-class (`4n-2` or `3n+1`, for example). After the match, it will check if the class is the same as informed in the css selector: if it is, apply the property; if not, don't.

---

To make it work correctly, use jQuery and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("li.title:even").css( "background-color", "#F30" );
$("li.title:nth-child(2n)").css( "background-color", "#F0F" );
```

*(You can use `$("li.title:nth-child(2n)")`, but it will have the same result as the example shown above)*

You can even create an array and apply the properties by a loop:

```js
var colorArr = [ "#FF0", "#00F" ];

$("li.title").each(function(key){
  $(this).css("background-color", colorArr[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="title">1</li>
   <li class="item">2</li>
   <li class="item">3</li>
   <li class="title">4</li>
   <li class="item">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **Firstly**: It's not working because the correct name of this pseudo-class is [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).
**Secondly**: It won't work because the `nth-of-type` get's it `2n` element of the tag with the class (`.title`) within its parent: the `<li>` inside `<ul>`, the `2n` `<li>` would be `<li class="item">a</li>`, `<li class="item">c</li>` and `<li class="item">a</li>`. As they don't have the `.title`, they won't change color.

Comment: Hey the jquery array is nice but how to make it loop if like 5 colors but 100 .title items?

Comment: Using remainder [%](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) will loop between 0 and color array length: `$(this).css("background-color", colorArr[key % colorArr.length])`.